# ng-repeat inside directive is not working after page refresh

Tags: angularjs

I have a requirement where i have created a directive like below
This is my below code:

```
app.directive('accPositiontab', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller:'cgiAccountPositionsController',
    controllerAs: 'pos',
    templateUrl:'src/html/pages/account-positions.page.html',
    translude:true,
    reloadOnSearch: false
    };
});
```

Now i am using ng-repeat inside the above directive the data is loading on page load but after page refresh the collection is not loading.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your scope data (model) into directive , then it will not hide after page refresh

Try this way.

```
var app = angular.module('BOneApp', []);

app.directive('jqGrid', function ($compile) {

    var jqGridCounter = 0;

    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            gridData: '='
        },
        template: '<div>' +
            '<table></table>' +
            '<div class="jqgrid-pagination"></div>' +
            '</div>',
        controller: function ($scope, $element) {
            $scope.editRow = function (row) {
               $element.find('table').editRow(row);
            };
            $scope.saveRow = function (row) {
                $element.find('table').saveRow(row);
            };
            $scope.restoreRow = function (row) {
                $element.find('table').restoreRow(row);
            };
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {
            var gridNumber = jqGridCounter++;
            var wrapperId = 'jqgrid-' + gridNumber;
            element.attr('id', wrapperId);

            var tableId = 'jqgrid-table-' + gridNumber;
            var table = element.find('table');
            table.attr('id', tableId);

            var pagerId = 'jqgrid-pager-' + gridNumber;
            element.find('.jqgrid-pagination').attr('id', pagerId);

            table.jqGrid({
                url: scope.gridData.url,
                datatype: "json",
                height: 'auto',
                colNames: scope.gridData.colNames || [],
                colModel: scope.gridData.colModel || [],
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                pager: '#' + pagerId,
                sortname: 'id',
                toolbarfilter: true,
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: "asc",
                gridComplete: function () {
                    var ids = table.jqGrid('getDataIDs');
                    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                        var cl = ids[i];
                        var be = "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-default' tooltip='Edit Row' tooltip-append-to-body='true' ng-click='editRow(" + cl + ")'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></button>";

                        var se = "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-default' tooltip='Save Row' tooltip-append-to-body='true' ng-click='saveRow(" + cl + ")'><i class='fa fa-save'></i></button>";

                        var ca = "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-default' tooltip='Cancel' tooltip-append-to-body='true' ng-click='restoreRow(" + cl + ")'><i class='fa fa-times'></i></button>";

                        table.jqGrid('setRowData', ids[i], {
                            act: be + se + ca
                        });
                    }
                },
                editurl: scope.gridData.editurl,
                caption: "SmartAdmin jQgrid Skin",
                multiselect: true,
                autowidth: true

            });
            table.jqGrid('navGrid', '#' + pagerId, {
                edit: true,
                add: true,
                del: true
            });
            table.jqGrid('inlineNav', '#' + pagerId);


            element.find(".ui-jqgrid").removeClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content");
            element.find(".ui-jqgrid-view").children().removeClass("ui-widget-header ui-state-default");
            element.find(".ui-jqgrid-labels, .ui-search-toolbar").children().removeClass("ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr");
            element.find(".ui-jqgrid-pager").removeClass("ui-state-default");
            element.find(".ui-jqgrid").removeClass("ui-widget-content");

            // add classes
            element.find(".ui-jqgrid-htable").addClass("table table-bordered table-hover");
            element.find(".ui-jqgrid-btable").addClass("table table-bordered table-striped");

            element.find(".ui-pg-div").removeClass().addClass("btn btn-sm btn-primary");
            element.find(".ui-icon.ui-icon-plus").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-plus");
            element.find(".ui-icon.ui-icon-pencil").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-pencil");
            element.find(".ui-icon.ui-icon-trash").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-trash-o");
            element.find(".ui-icon.ui-icon-search").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-search");
            element.find(".ui-icon.ui-icon-refresh").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-refresh");
            element.find(".ui-icon.ui-icon-disk").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-save").parent(".btn-primary").removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-success");
            element.find(".ui-icon.ui-icon-cancel").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-times").parent(".btn-primary").removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-danger");

            element.find(".ui-icon.ui-icon-seek-prev").wrap("<div class='btn btn-sm btn-default'></div>");
            element.find(".ui-icon.ui-icon-seek-prev").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-backward");

            element.find(".ui-icon.ui-icon-seek-first").wrap("<div class='btn btn-sm btn-default'></div>");
            element.find(".ui-icon.ui-icon-seek-first").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-fast-backward");

            element.find(".ui-icon.ui-icon-seek-next").wrap("<div class='btn btn-sm btn-default'></div>");
            element.find(".ui-icon.ui-icon-seek-next").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-forward");

            element.find(".ui-icon.ui-icon-seek-end").wrap("<div class='btn btn-sm btn-default'></div>");
            element.find(".ui-icon.ui-icon-seek-end").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-fast-forward");

            $(window).on('resize.jqGrid', function () {
                table.jqGrid('setGridWidth', $("#content").width());
            });

            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
    }
});


app.controller('ngConnect', function ($scope) {

    $scope.gridData = {
        url: "/Tables/Read",
        editurl: "/Tables/Edit",
        colNames: ['Actions', 'Inv No', 'Date', 'Client', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total', 'Notes'],
        colModel: [
            {
                name: 'act',
                index: 'act',
                sortable: false
            },
            {
                name: 'id',
                index: 'id'
            },
            {
                name: 'date',
                index: 'date',
                editable: true
            },
            {
                name: 'name',
                index: 'name',
                editable: true
            },
            {
                name: 'amount',
                index: 'amount',
                align: "right",
                editable: true
            },
            {
                name: 'tax',
                index: 'tax',
                align: "right",
                editable: true
            },
            {
                name: 'total',
                index: 'total',
                align: "right",
                editable: true
            },
            {
                name: 'note',
                index: 'note',
                sortable: false,
                editable: true
            }
        ]
    };




});
```